# merging two columns don´t work in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes.

```
df1:

     Municipio  puentes
0  CORU¥A (A)       94
1   CULLEREDO       11
2        FENE        7
3      FERROL       52
4    FISTERRA        2
```

and:

```
df2:

     Municipio  metros
0   CORU¥A (A)    28500
1    CULLEREDO     3211
2  ESTRADA (A)      498
3         FENE      698
4       FERROL     6211
```

I try to merge it:

```
df3=pd.merge(df1, df2, on="Municipio")
```

but df3 is empty!!!

If i try

```
df3=pd.merge(df1, df2, on="Municipio", how="outer")
```

df 3 contain the "Municipio" items two times:

```
    Municipio   metros  puentes
123 CORU¥A (A)  nan     94.0
30  CORU¥A (A)  28500.0 nan 
124 CULLEREDO   nan    11.0
31  CULLEREDO   3211.0 nan
```

any idea??? thanks!!!

SOLVED with "unutbu" help!!!

by "unutbu" request:
If i did:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, on="Municipio", how="outer").sort_values(by="Municipio").head().to_dict('lis‌​t')
```

Out:

```
{'Municipio': ['CORU¥A (A)',
  'CORU¥A (A) ',
  'CULLEREDO',
  'CULLEREDO ',
  'ESTRADA (A) '],
 'metros': [nan, 28500.0, nan, 3211.0, 498.0],
 'puentes': [94.0, nan, 11.0, nan, nan]}
```

and ... it´s a empty space ....

Comment: Please post `pd.merge(df1, df2, on="Municipio", how="outer").head().to_dict('list')`. This will show an unambiguous representation of the first few values.

Comment: I added it to the initial question, thanks in advance

Comment: Oops, it would be useful to see two rows that should have merged. Would you please post `pd.merge(df1, df2, on="Municipio", how="outer").sort_values(by="Municipio").head().to_dict('list')`.

Comment: I did it and... it´s an empty space in one of them.... that is the problem.... thanks a lot!!!